# What do you call a person who is new in town?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was just wondering if there is a single word for the person who has recently moved to the new city or new in town.

Comment: “The new kid in town.” (SCNR)

Comment: The phrase "new in town" is extremely common in this scenario, even though it's not a single word. "Excuse me, I'm new in town and need to get to the train station" "Hi, are you new in town?" etc

Answer (score 23):

I think what you're looking for is ***Newcomer***.

> (noun) 1. a person or thing that has recently arrived; new arrival:
>
> *She is a newcomer to our city.*
> *The firm is a newcomer in the field of advertising.*

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/newcomer)

Answer (score 9):

***Newcomer*** was my first thought but, depending on the context, ***incomer*** may also be suitable.

> [**incomer**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incomer) **Noun** *British*
>   A person who has come to live in an area in which they have not grown up, especially in a close-knit rural community.

Comment: While you can lose your *newcomer* status, in many rural places you'll never lose your *incomer* status.

Comment: Quite so, @Chris H. Years ago I met an Englishwoman in the Swiss village of Blonay. She told me that she and her Silician husband had always been referred to as _**the new people**_ in the village, even after having lived there for 35 years.

Comment: I can tell you that the word 'incomer' is not in common usage in Britain.

Comment: Nor in Australia, @AJFaraday but just because it's not being used doesn't mean it shouldn't be used. Abid could bring _incomer_ to new prominence—or not.

Comment: Sounds like a perfectly cromulent idea to me ;)

Comment: Aha! Thank you for your winkie. As a newbie, I have refrained from using emoticons lest I appear gauche or less than appropriately serious. "Cromulent"—not very euphonious, is it? :-)

Comment: @AJFaraday I have no doubt that _incomer_ is not in common usage in Britain. I did, however, just hear _incomers_ used in an episode of British detective series [_**Shetland**_](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2396135/Shetland) (2013–), which aired here in Australia on 19 August 2017. Fancy that!

Answer (score 3):

I've heard people out west say, greenhorn, though typically it means something equivalent to a rookie, it can also mean a newcomer usually to a rural area.

*Greenhorn* ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/greenhorn))

> 1
>   :  an inexperienced or naive person
>
> 2
>   :  a newcomer (as to a country) unacquainted with local manners and customs

Answer (score 3):

***Johnny-come-lately*** ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Johnny-come-lately))

This isn't nearly as common as the other answers in this thread, but it's a colorful, American phrase and deserves mention.

> 1:  a late or recent arrival: newcomer
>
> 2:  upstart